# Returning Null in Hibernate Search StringBridge

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I was reading over the javadoc comments for the StringBridge interface and on the objectToString method it says

> The return string must not be null. It can be empty though.

I was wondering what the reason for that was. I was under the impression that null values would be ignored when writing to the index, which is what I'm aiming to do. Is that the case or does returning null cause issues? If it does, would returning an empty string be ignored during indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, null is handled safely during indexing and will be ignored, unless you set `indexNullAs` in your field definition, in which case the null token will be indexed instead.

**EDIT**: Also, yes, returning an empty string when indexing would effectively be ignored, because searches won't match an empty string.

However, a null value returned by your bridge is *not* handled safely:

- **when querying**, because we generally expect the input value to be null, and not the output from the bridge, when one wants to look for null values in the index.
- for bridges used in document identifiers, which obviously must always return a non-null result
- for faceting when the property value is not null and your bridge turns it into a null value (this is probably a bug)

So your should be safe if:

- You don't use faceting
- You don't use this bridge for a document identifier (`@DocumentId`)
- You use `ignoreFieldBridge` when querying, or you only ever pass values that you know will not result in a null value being returned by the bridge

You must have noticed by now that it's simpler to not return null values at all...

Source: looked at the source code in Hibernate Search 5.10.0-SNAPSHOT (which, in this specific case, is probably identical to most earlier versions).

- `org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder#createQuery(org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.FieldContext, org.hibernate.search.bridge.spi.ConversionContext)`
- `org.hibernate.search.bridge.util.impl.String2FieldBridgeAdaptor#set`
- `org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity#addFacetDocValues`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the information! Yeah, I'll definitely make a point to use an empty string instead.